# Qt and X11 fullscreen application , which blocks Window Manager simultaneously

Tags: c++, qt, xorg

i think i need to use a XEvent with QMainWindow together to make my application unable to close even by Window Manager , could any one provide an example ?

It's like a fullscreen video game , which blocks all keyboards , mouse buttons.

P.S: QWidget::grabKeyboard() && QWidget::grabMouse() doesn't work when i try to switch to other applications with key combinations like "ALT_TAB"

Thanks.

Comment: Might be a bit late to ask, but I'm trying to do the exact same thing. How did you do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To completely block all inputs from other apps, you need to use `XGrabServer` and not `XGrabKeyboard`/`XGrabPointer` combination. Dunno whether Qt has an API for that but you can always call the Xlib function directly.

I however recommend against it. If the application is for some reason doesn't release the grab, you're stuck and need to escape to the console to kill it.

Comment: I hate apps that can't ALT+TAB!

Comment: It's designed to be like that , huh. But , i grabbed the whole screen  , mouse & keyboard jammed and my application not showing up , it's wired , but anyway it worked !

Answer (score 0):

I think you can override **closeEvent()** of your main window and reject the event by using **ignore()** method as described [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwidget.html#closeEvent).